# Android - ObjectAnimator set pivot value

Tags: android, pivot, android-animation, scaleanimation

I want a relative layout to scale up and the bottom of the view should be fixed.
I have a relative layout -

```
private RelativeLayout rlOutdoorSection;
```

Initialized it -

```
rlOutdoorSection = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlOutdoorSection);
```

Created an ObjectAnimator -

```
scaleUpOutdoor = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rlOutdoorSection, "scaleY", 1f,
            2.6f);
    scaleUpOutdoor.setDuration(3000);
```

start the Animation -

```
scaleDownOutdoor.start();
```

At present the view is getting scaled with pivot values at the center of the view.

How can i ensure the view is scaled with the bottom of the view fixed?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we have to calculate the `HEIGHT` of the view -

```
iOutdoorCompressedHeight = rlOutdoorSection.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Use this `height` as the pivot around which the view has to be scaled.

```
rlOutdoorSection.setPivotX(0f);
rlOutdoorSection.setPivotY(iOutdoorCompressedHeight);
```

The trick here can be getting the measured height of the view.
In an `Activity` calculate the height in

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // Here calculate the height / width
}
```

In a `FRAGMENT` use global layout listener-

```
rlOutdoorSection = (RelativeLayout) vMain
            .findViewById(R.id.rlOutdoorSection);
    ViewTreeObserver vtoOutdoor = rlIndoorSection.getViewTreeObserver();
    vtoOutdoor.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            iOutdoorCompressedHeight = rlOutdoorSection.getMeasuredHeight();
            rlOutdoorSection.setPivotX(0f);
            rlOutdoorSection.setPivotY(iOutdoorCompressedHeight);

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help some one.